# use jQuery.load() to include a php file in a div, wp_query() is part of php file

Tags: ajax, page-template

I have two php files; one is called `page-my-template.php`, and in it, I have a `<div></div>` which I would like to contain all the code from another php file called `my-content.php`.  I thought this would be simple but it is proving to be a huge headache.

Before I continue, *I am not using* JSON, *I am not using any forms or passing data*, and *I am not writing a plugin*.  I simply have a template file that only is used once on my page called `page-my-template.php`, and I need to dynamically call the code from `my-content.php` in a div.  It seems natural to use `jQuery.load()`, but no, please read below.

Inside the file `my-content.php`, I am using many core functions such as get_option(), WP_Query(), etc.  Of course these are causing 500 errors if I use `jQuery.load("my-content.php")`.  I realize I need to go through `admin-ajax.php` in order to do this the proper way.

I've spent a lot of time reading tutorials about how to use ajax with Wordpress.  All the tutorials I see on how to use ajax with Wordpress are very complicated and cover far more than what I am seeking, such as creating custom hooks, using forms, and writing plugins.  Is there a simple way to include the functionality of `admin-ajax.php`, so that I have access to the Wordpress core methods as I call the `my-content.php` file?  If so, please tell me what the code would be to include it, and exactly where to put that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using AJAX in WordPress is fundamentally pretty simple.

You need a function that handles the AJAX request, and a couple of `add_action` calls to map that function to the `action` you pass to `admin-ajax.php`, in this case, `some_action`:

```
function wpd_ajax_function() {
    get_template_part( 'my-content' );
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_some_action', 'wpd_ajax_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_some_action', 'wpd_ajax_function' );
```

This would go in your theme's `functions.php` file. You can see that all the function does is load your `my-content.php` file, and then exits execution.

Once you have that in place, you can test this by visiting `admin-ajax.php` in your browser with your `some_action` action appended:

```
http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=some_action
```

and you should see your output. If you hit that URL with your `jQuery.load()` code, you should have everything you need.

Comment: Great, I'll try that out at work tomorrow.  Looking forward to it.

Comment: This worked beautifully, but what if I need to do this for more than one file that will be called via ajax, such as elsewhere in the site?

Comment: You could pass an extra parameter with the request that indicates different files you want to load, or you could simply add additional functions and map them to a different action.

Comment: So would it be:
function wpd_ajax_function($num) {
    get_template_part( "my-content"$num ); ...

Then,
http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=some_action&num=1
(etc.)

Comment: Sorry I can't use code in comments!  At least that I know of.

Comment: You could do it that way, though I suggest validating the passed value in some way, depending on what it is, make sure it is what you expect so you're not just including arbitrary filenames you don't intend to.